# Standard interface for no argument function

Tags: java, shared-libraries, java-6

Is there in Java 6 (or any compatible library) standard interface for no argument function and generic return type.

Something like:

```
interface Foo<T> {
      T call();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a `Supplier<T>` - it takes nothing, and supplies with `T`. And the `abstract` method it defines is nice to be called `get()`

```
interface Supplier<T> {
   T get();
}
```

Note that in Java8, this (`@FunctionalInterface`) already exists (it's called [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)), so if you run your code under Java8, there's no need to define a custom interface.

Also, if you run your code under some pre-Java8 version, then you can use the Guava's [`Supplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) interface.

Comment: can you send a full qualified name of that interface (with package)?

Comment: At least it's not part of Java 6, as it was asked for in the question.

Comment: Great I just found out that com.google.common.base.Supplier interface is available in Guava.